# removing a backslash followed by a new line from a string

Tags: c#, replace

How can I remove a backslash and an immediately following new line from a string?

```
public class removeSlash : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string testString = @"374 373 372 \
371 370 369 368 367 366 365 ";
    
    [Button]
    void CleanString()

    {
        Debug.Log(testString.Replace("\n", ""));
        Debug.Log(testString.Replace("\\", ""));
        Debug.Log(testString.Replace("\\\n", ""));
    }
}
```

The first line removes the new line, the second line removes the backslash, but the third line does not remove either. I only want to remove new lines that come immediately after a backslash so I can't do it separately.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this in .NET 6. It removes both just fine for me.

Comment: `"\\\\n"` / `@"\\n"`

Comment: Perhaps there's a (hidden) space between the backslash and the newline, or something?

Comment: It seems like there is some hidden character, if I split on " ", then the "\" becomes index [^2] of the resulting slice, not [^1]

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/eGbNK3/1

Comment: regex did the trick thanks